# how do I get Google-earth to work on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, google-earth

I have followed exactly the precise instructions from JoKeR (March 2012)--removed all previous g-e files, downloaded and installed the current one.  No change at all: the logo appears, and vanishes right away.  Help?? thanks in advance. R.
Thanks, Mike for your answer. trying to start it in terminal produces a long list of error messages, the end of which I captured in a screenshot.  If you let me know where to send it, perhaps you can decipher the problem.  Cheers, R.

Comment: Have you install all dependencies?  see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth

Comment: When you try to start it from terminal by $ google-earth, does it output any errors? I just downloaded Google Earth .deb on 12.04 from Google http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html and it worked without any special instructions, no dependencies problems.